# How do I monitor the daily flow of funds at Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

1. How do I monitor the daily flow of funds in time to disable my instance.
2. What will happen if I come to the end of the month the account to which I did not expect? I was going to spend $100, but because Google considers costs only at the end of the month, i'm not disabled instance in time.
3. Instance does not automatically shut down if there is overspending? How could this be?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can now enable billing logs to be written to a Cloud Storage bucket every day, see the [announcement for programmatic access to billing data](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/12/ow-get-programmatic-access-to-your-billing-data-with-new-billing-api.html).
2. A new billing log file is created daily with data from the previous day. You can check that log (or write a script to check it) to find out if you're headed towards spending more than your budget for the month.
3. There is not currently a way to specify your budget, so no automatic actions can be taken (shutting down instances for example.)